# Android: How to handle all possibilities of intent send from other application

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am currently allow application to send files to my application so my application can send this file to a device which will display it. I used Action_Send / Action_View.

I realised the intent sent from other application may not be the same.

This is what i have implemented.

For Action_Send

The Extra_Stream will have a Uri of the data. In this uri, if it has a scheme content://

I will get save the store.

```
private string HandleImportUriWithContentProvider(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        var context = Forms.Context;
        var document = DocumentFile.FromSingleUri(context, uri);

        using (var stream = context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
        {
            var mime = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(document.Name);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mime))
            {
                var file = FileUtilities.SaveStreamToApplicationCache(context, stream, document.Name);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                {
                    App.IsCachedFile = true;
                    return file;//await App.ReceiveFileFromThirdParty(file, isStartup);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

otherwise it just a file path.

The Action_View, the data can be either content:// or path

if it was content:// I will do the same as above reading stream through the context.ContentResolver.

Is there other thing I am missing.

I understand that every application can send different data.

Comment: If Xamarin's `DocumentFile` matches Android's `DocumentFile`, do **not** use `document.Name` as the basis for a file extension. `document.Name` is a display name and does not have to have any file extension. Use a `ContentResolver` and `getType()` to get the MIME type associated with a `Uri`. Also, a `Uri` that has a scheme other than `content` is not "just a file path". A `Uri` always has a scheme (e.g., `file`, `http`, etc.). For `ACTION_SEND`, that schema can be anything. For `ACTION_VIEW`, you advertise what schemes you support in your `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: will getType be null at some point? For Action_Send I can use scheme filter to filter out the file coz I only taking care of the file in the local files. Will the scheme ever be null as well.

Comment: "will getType be null at some point?" -- it should not be `null`, though you may want to check for that as part of defensive programming. "Will the scheme ever be null as well" -- it too should not be `null`, though you may want to check for that as part of defensive programming.

Comment: I used the Gallery in the emulator and realised that the scheme property in intent object was null but in uri.scheme is was content. I don't know about file path itself. It can be file:// or /storage/0/something